# Upload large ebook file to Amazon

Tags: amazon-s3, upload, epub

Is there a way to upload a large ebook (above 100MB) like epub/mobi to Amazon?

I already try uploading to Amazon, but it says the file exceeds 20MB.

Comment: are you looking for some code to do this work?

Comment: No, I'm trying to find any solution not just coding

Comment: What do you mean by "upload to Amazon"? How did you attempt to upload it when you received the "file exceeds 20MB" message? Are you referring to Amazon S3, or do you wish to publish the book via Amazon's book services? Please provide as much information as possible so that we can assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool like [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) is what you need.

> S3cmd is a free command line tool and client for uploading, retrieving and managing data in Amazon S3 and other cloud storage service providers that use the S3 protocol, such as Google Cloud Storage or DreamHost DreamObjects. It is best suited for power users who are familiar with command line programs. It is also ideal for batch scripts and automated backup to S3, triggered from cron, etc.

simple example below:

```
s3cmd put file0-1.epub s3://BUCKET_NAME_HERE/test-upload.epub
```

Assuming you already configured aws key and secret through `aws configure`

Comment: Thank you, I need to try this first before accepting this answer

Comment: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: Am I able to publish the uploaded ebook from s3 with Amazon KDP?

Comment: Well you can use it from anywhere but it should have aws CLI with s3cmd on it